# Why does the emission of dansyl group diminish with time in this experiment?

Tags: biochemistry, fluorescence

I don't know how to make sense of this. I what is happening when an enzyme (carboxypeptidase, which contains tryptophan as its only chromophore and uses a Zn(II) ion in its active center) hydrolises a dansyl-Gly-Phe peptide. The enzyme and the peptide are mixed and the reaction is studied by fluorescence measurements: the whole reaction is excited with 280 nm light, and emissions at 310 nm (for Trp) and 550 nm (dansyl) are studied (see the two graphs below).

[image]

All I know is that this is an energy transfer process, which is known to lose effectiveness following a $1/r^{6}$ law regarding distance between emitter and absorber. Also, I know how Trp and dansyl emission spectra overlap, and I know that the enzyme is active but does not show fluorescence if Co(II) is used instead of Zn(II). My guess is that Trp emits light which is absorbed by the dansyl group due to the overlap in their emission/absorbance diagrams, but I don't see why the dansyl emission graph would go down w/ time. Isn't the number of dansyl groups constant, even if they are not bonded to the peptide in the end.

[image]

Comment: I agree it is confusing. You expect the trp fluorescence to be quenched by dipole-dipole transfer to the Dansyl so the trp fluorescence decreases and the Dansyl increases as the reaction proceeds. If the detector measures negative signal as the intensity increases the data makes more sense. Ignore the horizontal signals and initial signal 1/4 of a square  as this is probably due to scattering from the duration of the excitation source used. (btw Forster dipole transfer is  non-radiative transfer, D to A, not fluorescence and reabsorption. The spectral overlap ensures energy conservation.)